# How to match Arabic Unicode characters in a string with Java?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, arabic

Greetings All;

I have a desktop java application which gives the following output in the console window:

```
[
{
"ew" : "ana"
"hws" : [
"\u0623\u0646\u0627"
]
}
]
```

I would like to separate this string:"\u0623\u0646\u0627" from the whole output in order to do further processing on this string only.

I don't know how to do that? But one of the ideas is to use REGEX.
But how could I do that?

Would you help me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the console output to some other program?

Comment: This looks like JSON -- why dont you use a JSONParser to read out value of `hws`?

Comment: @Ingo No, but I want to convert the unicoded characters into arabic characters

Comment: @Nishan I am a very beginner in java so I don't know how to implement your idea?!

Comment: You must not confuse external and internal representations. Arabic characzers are unicode characters. How they will be represented by some application is another story. I still do not know whether you want to process the output of some program in another program or if you have control over the application and want to change just the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additional information

> The output shall be arabic letters not
>   \u064A...etc. My idea was to search
>   the output till the \u064A... lines
>   and convert them to arabic. Have you
>   get my point? I don't know how to
>   solve this, I am a beginer in java.
>   Sorry for the confusion and thank you
>   for your response.

And that the input comes from [http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ar&text=ana,m­asry&&tl_app=1](http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en%7Car&text=ana,m%C2%ADasry&&tl_app=1) you can solve it like this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL googleUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ar&text=ana,m­asry&&tl_app=1");
    URLConnection googleUrlc = googleUrl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(googleUrlc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    Pattern wordRegex = Pattern.compile("\"(\\\\u[\\da-z]{4})+\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern charRegex = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([\\da-z]{4})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher wordMatch = wordRegex.matcher(inputLine);
        for (int i = 0; wordMatch.find(); i++) {
        StringBuffer arabicBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher charMatch = charRegex.matcher(wordMatch.group());
        for (int j = 0; charMatch.find(); j++) {
            arabicBuffer.appendCodePoint(Integer.valueOf(charMatch.group(1), 16));
        }
        if (0 < arabicBuffer.length()) {
            System.out.println(arabicBuffer.toString());
        }       
        } 
    }
    in.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Staffan for your help.I don't know what is the problem, but it does not work!!    Here is the code:`String input = "\u0623\u0646\u0627";
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[]*\\[\\s*\"(.*?)\"").matcher(input);
        String arabicString = match.find() ? match.group(1) : null;
        System.out.println(arabicString);`

Comment: @Daisy, of course not! Because in string input there are exactly 3 characters, and none of them is a backslash or an u. Instead, this are already the arabic characters you want. This is so because the java compiler replaces \uXXXX strings with the correspondng unicode character.

Comment: @Daisy in your example in the question you had a structure with curly and square brackets. But in the comment above it's only the arabic characters (as @Ingo says). I'll edit my solution above to include the creation of the input variable. I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Sorry for that.
Let me clarify I have a program that return the above console result "in separte lines as u see above" .
The idea of the application is to translitrate english letters to arabic via google transliterate as follows:

Comment: `import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class URLConnectionReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

URL googleUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ar&text=ana,masry&&tl_app=1");
        URLConnection googleUrlc = googleUrl.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(googleUrlc.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);

}//end while
in.close();
 }//end main
}//end class`

Comment: The output shall be arabic letters not \u064A\...etc.

My idea was to search the output till the \u064A\... lines and convert them to arabic.

Have you get my point? I don't know how to solve this, I am a beginer in java.

Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your response.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really helpful. I have one more question. The output from [http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ar&text=ana,masry&&tl_app=1](http://www.google.com/transliterate/arabic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|ar&text=ana,masry&&tl_app=1) is `
أنا
أن
أنى
انا
عن
مصري
مسري
مصر
مزري
مصرى` what if i want the first word from each input word. I mean for `ana` I want `أنا`only and for `masry` I want `مصرى`. Any Ideas? Also what is the best way to study java?